# django-tables2 ' table not displaying

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm working with Django-tables2. I can display a table using a model but can't get one to display using data. I change things but I'm not sure on how to get the table to display
view

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]

def Users(request):
    data = dictfetchall(cursor)
    table = ProjectTable(data)
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 4}).configure(data)
    return render(request, 'JiraAdmin/index.html', {'table': table})

table.py
class ProjectTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column(verbose_name='Role')
    lead = tables.Column(verbose_name='Lead')
    display_name = tables.Column(verbose_name='User)

class meta:
    attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
    attrs = {'class': 'table table-responsive', 'width': '100%'}
```

template

```
{% render_table ProjectTable %}
```

Changed my view

```
def Users(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(select)
    results =  cursor.fetchall()

        x = cursor.description
    resultsList = []
    for r in results:
            i = 0
            d = {}
            while i < len(x):
                d[x[i][0]] = r[i]
                i = i+1
            resultsList.append(d)
    table = ProjectTable(resultsList)
    return render_to_response('index.html', {"table": table})
```

html

```
<table>
{% for results in resultsList %}
    {% for field, value in results.get_fields %}
        <tr>
           {%render_table ProjectTable%}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}s
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i faced the same issue!
The Meta class should be named correctly, otherwise rendering is quite abrupt!

You have the class name as 'meta' rather than 'Meta'

Your tables.py should look some what like this!

```
table.py
class ProjectTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column(verbose_name='Role')
    lead = tables.Column(verbose_name='Lead')
    display_name = tables.Column(verbose_name='User)

    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-responsive', 'width': '100%'}
```

I know i'm pretty late on this thread, but this might be helpful for newcomers like me :)
Can you please try this and let me know if this solved the issue!

Answer (score -1):

Please inspect the data you are feeding into `ProjectTable`. If it's not a queryset, it should be a list of `dict`s, something like this:

```
[
    {'name': '...', 'lead': '...', 'display_name': '...'},
    {'name': '...', 'lead': '...', 'display_name': '...'},
    ...
]
```

Comment: When using:def dictfetchall(cursor):
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]  I would get a list of dicts. So I'm guessing I'm not parsing the file correctly in the html to display in the table

Comment: Does `table.as_values()` return what you expect?